# Wired to wireless ethernet adaptor?

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet

Is there a small standalone ethernet-wifi adaptor?  I'm looking for something that would plug straight into the RJ-45 jack and act as a wifi client.

Comment: what you want is called a wired to wireless ethernet bridge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[http://www.amazon.com/D-Link-Wireless-108AG-Gaming-Adapter/dp/B0006TIA0M](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0006TIA0M) Used this one myself, VERY RELIABLE one : 30+ days without reboot, no lags.

Comment: What kind of configuration tools do you use?  HTTP based?  Would this work under Linux?

Comment: @Daniel I've used it under Ubuntu Linux, FreeBSD and it is a seamless network device : it's just a "wire interface for wireless network". Not just HTTP webservices, but also Tor, games, FTP server, SVN and SSH. It does not require a driver, of course. Haven't tried a "sniff mode"/promicious mode to dump all Layer 2 packets, so can't tell you if this will work fine. But even if it will, it won't mirror wifi-specific packets for you, as far as I understand the device.

Comment: My question was more along the lines of "How do you tell it what to connect to?"

Comment: @Daniel it has a web interface, good one : can be controlled by cURL CLI tool, for example

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  There are many choices.  Search for wireless adapters with ethernet connection.

NETGEAR WNCE3001-100NAS is one such product.